# Will my laptop fit my handbag? (rectangle fits in parallelepiped)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am not crazy, this is an actual geometry question that I found interesting as a non math person.

I have a MacBook Pro 15 with dimensions $35 \times 24 \times 1.5$ and I want to buy a handbag and know if it will fit. The dimensions of the bag are $32 \times 20 \times 20$ (the typical maximum dimensions for the second handbag that airlines allow are $35 \times 20 \times 20$, but it would have been easier).

In the case of a $35 \times 20 \times 20$ bag it is very easy because you put the laptop by the diagonal of the bag ($\sqrt{32^2+20^2}=37.74 > 35$) if we count the height of the laptop as $0$ instead of $1.5$ (so considering it a Rectangle instead of a Parallelepiped).

In the case of a $32 \times 20 \times 20$ bag how can I calculate if it fits (putting the Rectangle laptop tilted in respect of 2 dimensions instead of 1 in the Parallelepiped)?

And how can I do the same calculations counting the height of the laptop as different from 0 (so counting both the laptop and the bag as Parallelepipeds)?

(If this doesn't belong to this sub Stack Exchange I am very happy to know where I should put this)

Comment: Yes, a very nice question!

Comment: It's tangential to the actual mathematical question, but you probably don't want a bag that would just barely fit your laptop when it is tilted in a specific way. I don't think it would be good for the laptop (e.g. if you put down the bag too hard, the ground/table is going to hit it straight at the corner). If possible, I would suggest trying out the bag with the laptop (as in, physically putting it inside) and checking if it looks like it fits fine before buying it.

Comment: @tomasz It will be only for some time, as those are the measures of a lot of low cost companies for the second hand baggage. I simply want to know if I have to put the laptop in my first hand bag (in the overhead compartment) or in my second one (under the seat in front).

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo: I've never needed more than one luggage piece, but if the bag is going to barely contain just the laptop anyway, why not just take the laptop itself as the second luggage piece?

Comment: If your math question starts with _I am not crazy_, then it's probably a nice question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, I think your laptop will fit in the second bag.
[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks! A little bit of elaboration on how you came up with that solutions? Is it a tool or simple drawing?

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo, it is just a simple drawing.

Comment: Sad to say, the drawing is inaccurate and the laptop does not fit in the bag this way.

Answer (score 4):

Let the bag be represented by a cuboid of dimensions $32 \times 20 \times 20$ be centered at the origin of a world coordinate frame, such that the cuboid extends along the $x$ axis from $-16$ to $+16$, and from $-10$ to $+10$ along the $y$ axis, and from $-10$ to $+10$ along the $z$ axis.

Place a rectangle of dimensions $35 \times 24$ on the $xy$ plane with edges parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes, such that its length extends from $-17.5$ to $+17.5$ along the $x$ axis, and from $-12$ to $+12$ along the $y$ axis.

We want to attach a reference frame to the rectangle, and rotate this frame in three consecutive rotations.  There are several ways to create the overall rotation, but I will choose the following sequence.  First rotate about the world $y$ axis by angle $-\theta$, then about the world $z$ by angle $\phi$, and finally about the local $x'$ axis by angle $\psi$.

Let $c_1 = \cos(\theta), s_1 = \sin(\theta), c_2 = \cos(\phi) , s_2 = \sin(\phi) , c_3 = \cos(\psi) , s_3 = \sin(\psi) $

Then the combined overall rotation matrix of the three consecutive rotations is given by

$ R = R_z( \phi ) R_y( - \theta)  R_x (\psi) $

And this is equal to

$ R =  \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && -s_2 && 0 \\ s_2 && c_2 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 && 0 && -s_1 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ s_1 && 0 && c_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && c_3 && - s_3 \\ 0 && s_3 && c_3 \end{bmatrix} $

And this evaluates to

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 c_2 && -c_2 s_1 s_3 - s_2 c_3 && - c_2 s_1 s_3 + s_2 s_3 \\ s_2 c_1 && - s_2 s_1 s_3 + c_2 c_3 && -s_2 s_1 c_3 - c_2 s_3 \\ s_1 && c_1 s_3 && c_1 c_3 \end{bmatrix} $

If a vertex of the rectangle is at $(a,b,0)$ , then its rotated version is at

$\begin{pmatrix} a c_1 c_2 - b (c_2 s_1 s_3 + s_2 c_3 ) \\ a s_2 c_1 + b ( -s_2 s_1 s_3 + c_2 c_3 ) \\ a s_1 + b c_1 s_3 \end{pmatrix} $

So if we take $a = 17.5 , b = 12 $ , then we want

$ 17.5 s_1 + 12 c_1 s_3 \le 10 $

and

$ 17.5 s_2 c_1 + 12 ( - s_2 s_1 s_3 + c_2 c_3 ) \le 10 $

Additionally, if we take $a = 17.5 , b = -12$ , then we also want

$ 17.5 c_1 c_2 + 12 (c_2 s_1 s_3 + s_2 c_3) \le 16 $

These are complicated expression involving the trigonometric ratios of the three rotation angles, and the only way I can think to find if the above inequalities can be satisfied simultaneously is brute force trial and error.

After running nested loops for $\theta, \phi , \psi$ over $[0, 360^\circ]$, I found that the conditions cannot be met.  So I concluded that the given rectangle cannot be placed in the given bag.

Repeating the iteration for a bag of dimensions $34.5 \times 23.5 \times 23$, I was able to place the rectangle in this new bag.

The angles are

$ \theta = 0^\circ $ (for rotation about world $y$ axis)

$ \phi = 27^\circ $ (for rotation about world $z$ axis)

$ \psi = 73^\circ $ (for rotation about local $x'$ axis)

The rotation matrix corresponding to these angles is

$R = \begin{bmatrix} 0.891007 && -0.13273 && 0.434153 \\ 0.45399 && 0.260505 && -0.85207 \\ 0 && 0.956305 && 0.292372 \end{bmatrix}$

The above mentioned vertices of the rectangle have the following coordinates after applying the rotation matrix

For $a = 17.5, b = 12 $, the rotated point is

$ (13.99981 , 11.07089, 11.47566) $

And for $a = 17.5 , b = -12$ the rotated point is

$(17.18542, 4.818773, -11.4757) $

Now, if we take the thickness of the laptop ($1.5$) into consideration, then the above rotation angles will not fit the $3D$ laptop inside the cuboid.  To make the real laptop fit, we have to increase the dimensions of the bag again.  This time I took the dimensions to be $34.4 \times 23 \times 23$.  And for the following angles, the laptop fits in the bag.

$ \theta = 7.5^\circ $ (about world $y$ axis)

$ \phi = 8^\circ$ (about world $z$ axis)

$ \psi = -47^\circ$ (about local $x'$ axis)

The following is a GIF animation showing the bag and the laptop inside it.

[image]

Comment: @Leucippus I've edited my solution since your last comment.  Please see if it provide an answer to the question now.  If so, please make adjustments to the review.

Comment: When I tried to reproduce your results for the first bag, with $\phi = 10.5^\circ$ and $\psi = -56^\circ$, the rectangle vertex at $(17.5,12,0)$ rotated to $(15.98,9.79,-9.95)$, which is good, but the vertex at $(17.5,-12,0)$ rotated to $(18.43,-3.41,9.95)$, outside the bag. Could you please edit the answer to show the explicit numerical values of your rotation matrix and the numerical coordinates of the corners of the rectangle after rotation so that I can check my attempt to reproduce your results?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my code.  I've corrected that, and when I ran the search loop, I found that it is not possible to fit the $35 \times 24$ rectangle inside the $32 \times 20 \times 20 $ cuboid.  However, I changed the size of the cuboid to $34.5 \times 23.5 \times 23 $ and was able to fit the rectangle in the bag, with $\theta = 0, \phi = -29^\circ, \psi = -73^\circ$.  I'll edit my answer shortly.